# Calling Web API from SQL Server when API is configured to use Windows Authentication

Tags: sql, asp.net-web-api, ssis, windows-authentication

I have an internal web site that is secured with Windows Authentication. This works correctly. 
Contained in the site I have several methods accessible via Web API.

The intent is to automate the calling of those API methods from a SQL 2008 SSIS job. This is our preferred process so that all scheduled tasks are in one place.

When I call the Web API from the desktop of a user that is in the appropriate AD security group the Web API call works properly but when I try to call the API from the SSIS job I get an access error. I have tried putting valid credentials in the SSIS job but that didn't work, I still get the same error.

What security context is this job running under? Can I add that security context to the AD group and get everything working?

Web API under a different authentication process? Can this be configured in web.Config or on the page itself?

**** Update

I've confirmed that the account I expected is the account that is doing the call.

I have more details on the exact error message being returned:

```
SSIS package "XXManagerAdd.dtsx" starting.

Error: 0x1 at Trigger API: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenRead(Uri address)
   at ST_4b03489e84c44950b38aac6439e328ee.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
Task failed: Trigger API
SSIS package "XXManagerAdd.dtsx" finished: Success.
```

Comment: If you've created a credential and assigned that as the entity running the job step, then you API call is going to use those credentials. The fact that it works under a user account and not from the job, leads me to believe things are not configured correctly there. We'd need to see more details to provide concrete, reproducible results

Comment: I've tested the SQL job by putting in the exact same credentials that I use to run the API from my web browser (basically my login)

Comment: `Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "WhoAmI", string.Format("I am {0}", System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name), string.Empty, 0, true);` Add a script task into a new package and that code should raise an information event with the name of the identity running the package. Run it once as yourself and once via a sql agent job with the credentialed user. That should verify whether the credentials are truly being presented